# Shortest closed Steiner chain of circles sandwiched between circumcircle and incircle of triangle

Tags: geometry, reference-request, triangles, circles

Consider [Steiner chain of circles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_chain)
with the external circle
of radius $R$,
the internal circle
of radius $r$ 
and $n$ circles in a chain
with the radii $r_1,\dots,r_n$.

Known condition for the distance $d$ between the centers of
the boundary circles is
defined by the two radii of the boundary circles
and the number $n$ of circles in a chain,
\begin{align}
d^2&=(R-r)^2-4rR\tan^2\tfrac\pi{n}
\tag{1}\label{1}
.
\end{align}

Since every triangle has an associated pair of circles,
circumscribed circle with circumradius $R$ 
and inscribed circle with inradius $r$
(one is always inside the other),
this pair of circles 
looks like a natural candidate
to use in construction 
of the Steiner chain of circles.

The distance between the centers
of the circumcircle and the incircle
is known to obey 
\begin{align}
d^2&=R(R-2r)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Let for simplicity set $R=1$. Then
relations \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}
suggest that
\begin{align}
r&=4\tan^2\tfrac\pi{n}
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

As we know that for triangles
$r$ must be less than of equal $\tfrac12$,
it follows that:

1) The Steiner chain of circles
can not be constructed
using circumcircle+incircle 
of the equilateral triangle (trivial to check).

2) The shortest Steiner chain of circles
sandwiched between the circumcircle
and the incircle of triangle
consists of $10$ (ten) circles,
all such triangles are strictly acute (for example, $\triangle UVW$),
and there are two isosceles 
($\triangle A_1B_1C_1$ and $\triangle A_2B_2C_2$ ) among them:

[image]

3) The shortest Steiner chain of circles
associated with the right-angled triangle 
has length $n=11$:

[image]

Question.

Are there any known references 
where this kind of relation 
between triangles and Steiner chains of circles
was examined in details?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Very interesting questions and results. I have never seen similar results.

Comment: @Jean Marie: Thanks. 
Actually, the list of related questions was shortened to minimum
to make the question more digestible.
interestingly, it seems that intuition fails in this case,
for example, the number 10 (as well as 11) was completely unexpected.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for sharing. There exist souces in French ( *chaîne de Steiner* or *cercle de Steiner*). http://mathafou.free.fr/pbg/sol139.html 
I like this animation  http://www.thedudeminds.net/?p=3324